# Get Specific Time in Specific TIme Zone

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a calendar object with the a specific time tomorrow in a specific time zone (not the time zone the device is in).  In the example below I want to get 12:15am in Central time zone tomorrow not matter where in the world the device is located.

First question, is this the best way to do this?

Second question, how should I deal with daylight savings.  I am only dealing with the 4 continental US time zones and I can assume that I want to adjust for daylight savings time.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"), Locale.getDefault());
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6); //Central time zone
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Calendar calendar =
   Calendar.getInstance(
       TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"),
       Locale.getDefault()
   );

calendar.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
calendar.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 15 );
calendar.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
calendar.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0 );

calendar.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1 );
```

The best way to do this is to use JodaTime, but I see that you have put android tag, so Calendar is probably your only option.

For a second question.  java.util.Calendar handles Daylight to Standard time conversion.

Comment: Joda-Time does run in Android.

Answer (score 0):

In Joda-Time…

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Chicago" );
DateTime tomorrowAfterMidnight = DateTime.now( timeZone ).plusDays(1).withTimeAtStartOfDay().plusMinutes(15);
```